# How to fix invalid syntax unknown error in Python django?

Tags: python, django

I am learning django and started to watch some tutorials, when I add url() function to urls.py, it gives an invalid syntax error

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home')
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]

url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You're missing a comma after the first pattern.

Comment: As a general rule: in the case of a SyntaxError, the line the error message points too is the line where the syntax error is detected, which is not necessarily the faulty line - most often, the problem is in one of the previous lines.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a comma after your first url() ("home") in the list. You'll want:

```
url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
```

Also, if you are just learning, consider using Django 2.1 with it's simplified URL syntax. Good luck!